# Givens rotation for QR decomposition with cuBlas functions cublasSrotg and cublasSrot

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, cublas

I am new to CUDA and I tried to implement a Givens rotation for QR decomposition with cuBlas libary.

I used

`cublasStatus_t cublasSrotg(cublasHandle_t handle,
float *a, float *b,
float *c, float *s)`

for calculating c and s and

`cublasStatus_t cublasSrot (cublasHandle_t handle, int n,
float *x, int incx,
float *y, int incy,
const float *c, const float *s)`

for roatation of an 1000 x 1000 matrix. As cublaSrotg() overwrites the parameters a and b with r and z, I am not able to use the matrix in device memory. But copying elements of the matrix to the host takes about 90 percent of any cycle of the loop. A implementation in C is up to three times faster.

Am i using it wrong? What will be a better alternative for Givens rotation on CUDA devices?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: You're having a performance issue with copies between host and device, yet you did not show us any of the code that performs the copying. Are you using pinned memory on the host and are you performing the copies in large batches? Also, how are you measuring the timings and have you tried looking at the timeline for you app in the CUDA profiler?

Comment: The problem I have is independent of copying. The function cublasSrotg overwrites a and b with intermediate data during calculation of c and s. (See CUDA Toolkit 4.1
CUBLAS Library, Page 30). So I am not able to call cublasSrotg with pointers to my initial matrix for a and b. Otherwise I have to copy them again to the inital matrix for calculation with cublasSrot. Correct?

Comment: I could not belive that this will be the correct use as it is quite ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a trick to perform `cublasSrotg` and `cublasSrot` several times on the same matrix, so i implemented my own kernel.

Meanwhile with `rhypot` there is an easier way with more performance

```
double t = rhypot(x, y);
double c = x * t;
double s = y * t;
```

See [CUDA Devblog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-fast-robust-computation-givens-rotations/)